# I am not able to access to my XAMPP server from another PC in same LAN

Tags: tomcat, xampp, lan

it looks to me like I am not the only one with this problem. I cannot access my XAMPP server, that is in a PC in a LAN, from other PC that is in the same LAN. I have tried even to swith off the firewall, but it did not work, that's not the reason. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the folder's sharing options to grant access to the xampp folder for your PC?